# ControlList which contains 2 items returns first items Text element for both items

Tags: atata

I have the following code:

```
public ControlList<PaymentItem, _> PaymentGroup { get; private set; }

[ControlDefinition("div[@id='grant-details']//div", ContainingClass = "payment-details", ComponentTypeName = "Payment Item")]
public class PaymentItem : Control<_>
{
     [FindByXPath("//a[contains(@class, 'test-payment-details-toggle')]")]
     public Link<_> Caret { get; private set; }

     [FindByXPath("//strong[text() = 'Special Instructions:']/parent::p")]
     public Text<_> SpecialInstructions { get; private set; }
}
```

When I run, the HTML in the source code has 2 div's that match the PaymentItem, the first one of them has the SpecialInstructions Text object with a string value of "None" while the second has some random text, but PaymentGroup[0].SpecialInstructions and PaymentGroup[1].SpecialInstructions both return the value of "None" - it seems to be performing the FindByXPath from the document root instead of the //div with the matching class - what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in incorrect XPath in `[FindByXPath("//strong[text() = 'Special Instructions:']/parent::p")]`. Either replace `//` in the beginning with `.//`, or just remove it (`.//` will be prepended under the hood by default).

- `//` - finds an element from the root of HTML document.
- `.//` - finds an element inside the element of parent Atata component.

*Additionally, I would simplify `[FindByXPath("//a[contains(@class, 'test-payment-details-toggle')]")]` to `[FindByClass("test-payment-details-toggle")]`. `Link<TOwner>` refers to `<a>` in its control definition anyway, so you just need to add a class selector.*